# Выравнивание контента в независимых div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать так, что бы контент второго `div` выравнивался снизу? Что бы два блока были одинакового размера без установки `height`?

```css
div {
  background: blue;
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
1<br>
2
</div>
<div>
1
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Выравнивание контента в независимых div... почему же независимых, они же рядом

```css
.first,.second {
    background: black;
    margin: 10px;
    color:white;
}
.container{
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="first">
        dasf
        <br>
        dasfd
        <br>
        dasf
    </div>
    <div class="second">
        asfasfds
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="gl">
1<br>
2
</div>
<div id="pod">
1
</div>
<script language="javascript">
{
var h = document.getElementById('gl').clientHeight;
var container=document.getElementById('pod');
container.style.height=h+"px"
}
</script>   
</body>

</html>
```

Вот так высота будет одинаковой.